# Screenshot app with option to take shots with specified pixel dimensions

Tags: screenshot

I am using the screenshot app that comes with elementary. Love it for its simplicity and works a treat, but I feel its missing a feature.

Namely, I would like the ability to take a screenshot based on user entered pixel dimensions.

Quite often when developing websites you may wish to have pictures of a specific dimension, usually to cut down on page load speed and avoid generating unnecessary overhead. For instance I have a need at the moment for a bunch of images at 750px x 400px. Now I can take a screenshot at 1920 x 1080 and go into gimp and edit it down but its an extra step that adds time...

Just one for the suggestion box ;)

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Use custom screenshot tool such as `Shutter`. If you look in the preferences - You can predefine multiple settings like resolution and compression ratio.

Here is how you can install it.

Add repository by typing (in the terminal):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa`

Followed by:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will like these options.

Resizer - **Quickly resize images from the context menu**
A simple image resizer that resizes one or more images, usable from the context menu or as a standalone app.
https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.peteruithoven.resizer/

Image Optimizer - **Simple lossless image compression**
https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.gijsgoudzwaard.image-optimizer/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 3rd party apps being a solution, eOS has a [place on their github](https://github.com/elementary/gala) for feature requests.